# civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', in hook_civicrm_pre?

Tags: api, hooks

Getting a loop and consequently out of memory while executing the code:

```
  function hook_civicrm_pre($op, $objectName, $id, &$params){
      if ('Individual' === $objectName && 'edit' === $op) {
     $myconditions = [];
     // make a few API calls checking Relationships, custom field balues, ets, gathering the data
     // print_r($myconditions) = $myconditions[TRUE, TRUE, TRUE];
   
   $condition = !in_array(false, $myconditions) ? 1 : 0;       
     
     // An individual custom field value update
       $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', [
                    'contact_type' => 'Individual',
                    'id' => $id,
                    'custom_999' => $condition,
                  ]);
   CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('Line '.__LINE__, print_r($result, true));
  }
 }
```

Have tried also

```
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
  if (0 === strpos($key, 'custom_999')) {
    $params[$key] = $condition;
}
```

}

Which doesn't seem to pick up the latest changes, eg., works only 2nd saving. Can't see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a contact update from within a contact update will cause an infinite loop. Instead of firing a new update action, just adjust the parameters of the action that's already happening. The `&$params` variable is passed by reference so you can modify it before the contact is written to the database.

Comment: Thanks a mil! I lost a plot for Contacts $params while digging into Relationships $params and API paths.

Comment: You don't need to use the API at all here, but in situations where you do then using APIv4 is much preferred now.